How to bind a Vector2 constant in gdextension and expose them in gdscript?
I have a constant in my class in gdextension as such:
class MyCustomClass : public Node2D
{
    GDCLASS(MyCustomClass, Node2D);

    public:
        const Vector2 MY_VECTOR = Vector2(100, 100);
        ...

}

how do I bind it in _bind_methods() as done for properties?
void MyCustomClass::_bind_methods()
{
   ADD_PROPERTY(PropertyInfo(Variant::FLOAT, "my_variable"), "set_my_variable", "get_my_variable");
}

I'm trying to achieve this in such a way that they are exposed in gdscript

I've spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to do this same thing for a string constant, from a module.  As far as I can tell, the only way to do it is to make a property or wrap it in a function.  I'm sure there are other ways as well, but not what we are looking for.
There is a way to create integer constants, with bind_integer_constant, but not anything for a generic Variant and name.  It may be worth implementing this myself, and sending in a patch.  If I do so, I'll come back and update this to let you know.
Hopefully someone else will correct me, but this is what I have figured out so far.
